# xgboost binary logistic regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, logistic-regression, xgboost

I am having problems running logistic regression with xgboost that can be summarized on the following example.

Lets assume I have a very simple dataframe with two predictors and one target variable:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'X1' : pd.Series([1,0,0,1]), 'X2' : pd.Series([0,1,1,0]), 'Y' : pd.Series([0,1,1,0], )})
```

I can post images because Im new here, but we can clearly see that when X1 =1 and X2=0, Y is 0 and when X1=0 and X2=1, Y is 1.

My idea is to build a model that outputs the probability that an observation belongs to each one of the classes, so if I run xgboost trying to predict two new observations (1,0) and (0,1) like so:

```
X = df[['X1','X2']].values            
y = df['Y'].values

params  = {'objective': 'binary:logistic',
          'num_class': 2
          } 

clf1 = xgb.train(params=params, dtrain=xgb.DMatrix(X, y), num_boost_round=100)                    
clf1.predict(xgb.DMatrix(test.values))
```

the output is:

```
array([[ 0.5,  0.5],
       [ 0.5,  0.5]], dtype=float32)
```

which, I imagine, means that for the first observation, there is 50% chance it belonging to each one of the classes.

I'd like to know why wont the algorithm output a proper (1,0) or something closer to that if the relationship between the variables is clear.

FYI, I did try with more data (Im only using 4 rows for simplicity) and the behavior is almost the same; what I do notice is that, not only the probabilities do not sum to 1, they are often very small like so:
(this result is on a different dataset, nothing to do with the example above)

```
array([[ 0.00356463,  0.00277259],
       [ 0.00315137,  0.00268578],
       [ 0.00453343,  0.00157113],
```

Comment: Are your two predictors just 0s and 1s? If so there are only 4 possible combinations of your features and thus should only expect (at most) 4 unique probability predictions.

Comment: yes they are. Ok, only 4 possible combinations, makes sense, but not sure how does that answer my question.

Comment: I'm confused, what is your question? I thought you didn't understand why there was little variance in your probability predictions.

Comment: my question is: why is the prediction (0.5, 0.5 -meaning 50% chance of being class 1 and 50% chance of being class 0)  is if it clear that when  X1 =1 and X2=0, Y is 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok - here's what is happening..

The clue as to why it isn't working is in the fact that in the smaller datasets it cannot train properly.  I trained this exact model and observing the dump of all the trees you will see that they cannot split.

(tree dump below)

*NO SPLITS, they have been pruned!*

`[1] "booster[0]" "0:leaf=-0"  "booster[1]" "0:leaf=-0"  "booster[2]" "0:leaf=-0" 
 [7] "booster[3]" "0:leaf=-0"  "booster[4]" "0:leaf=-0"  "booster[5]" "0:leaf=-0" 
[13] "booster[6]" "0:leaf=-0"  "booster[7]" "0:leaf=-0"  "booster[8]" "0:leaf=-0" 
[19] "booster[9]" "0:leaf=-0"`

**There isn't enough weight is each of the leaves to overpower** `xgboost`'s **internal regularization** (which penalizes it for growing)

This parameter may or may not be accessible from the python version, but you can grab it from `R` if you do a github install

http://xgboost.readthedocs.org/en/latest/parameter.html

> lambda [default=1] L2 regularization term on weights
>
> alpha [default=0] L1 regularization term on weights

basically this is why your example trains better as you add more data, but  cannot train at all with only 4 examples and default settings.